# Rewrite web server apache for IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to translate htaccess rewrite rule for a IIS web server, can you help me with the sintax? for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=([0-9]+)&pagesize=([0-9]+)&pagenumber([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^[OLD-SLUG]$ https://www.[DOMAIN].it/[NEW-SLUG]? [R=301,L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^[OLD-SLUG]$ - [G]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many PHP applications currently ship with rewrite rules as part of their .htaccess file. These rules tell Apache's mod_rewrite how and when to rewrite incoming requests. The IIS URL Rewrite module can read these rules and translate them into URL Rewrite rules.

For more information about importing Apache mod_rewrite rules, see: [Importing Apache mod_rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).